# Python Inserting a String Into a List After Three Numbers Have Been Printed

Tags: python-3.x, list

Basically, I'm doing a challenge where i need to take the last letter from each word and move it to the front of the word, i also need to add mu at the end of each word and i need to add emu after three words have been displayed. The part I need help on is adding emu after 3 words (In the for loop). I tried taking a variable and adding 1 to it each time i get a number from the list and then checking whether number % 3 == 0 and then inserting 'emu' after it. Even though i reset number to its starting value after i insert emu once, it doesnt insert in the correct spot the next time number % 3 == 0

Here is the current output:

```
imu emu odmu tnomu emu wknomu whomu otmu odmu sthimu
```

What I would like is:

```
imu odmu tnomu emu wknomu whomu otmu emu odmu sthimu
```

```
sentence = 'i do not know how to do this'
sentence = sentence.split()

sentence = " ".join([words[-1:] + words[:-1] + 'mu' for words in sentence])

sentence = sentence.split()

number = 0
for words in sentence:
  index = sentence.index(words)

  if number % 3 == 0 and number != 0:
    number = 0
    sentence.insert(index, 'emu')
  else:
    number += 1

sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
print(sentence)
```

Comment: Just from a brief overview, you might want to look into using `enumerate` in your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `enumerate` to get the index while iterating.

```
sentence = 'i do not know how to do this'
sentence = sentence.split()

sentence = " ".join([words[-1:] + words[:-1] + 'mu' for words in sentence])
result = []
for idx, word in enumerate(sentence.split()):
     if idx > 1 and idx % 3 == 0:
             result.append("emu")
     result.append(word)

print(" ".join(result))
```

Another mistake you are doing is inserting element into an array while iterating it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although this does work, I was curious if there is a way for it to print out on one line?